# Plus sign in front of Time. Assigning formula to cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have time (hh:mm) cell in Sheet1 and I'd like to show it's value in Sheet2 prefixed with a plus sign (+00:01).

I came up with `="+"&TEXT(Sheet1!$A$1, "hh:mm")`. It works fine but I don't know how to code it in VBA.

I have this so far:

`result_cell.Formula = "=""+""&TEXT(" & ?????? & ", ""hh:mm"")"`

I have no idea what should go in place of question marks.

Comment: I think is something like this: result_cell.Formula = "=""+""&TEXT(Sheet1!$A$1, ""hh:mm"")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can put the `+` inside the `TEXT` function

```
=TEXT(Sheet1!$A$1, "+hh:mm")
```

Now in VBA

```
result_cell.Formula = "=TEXT(Sheet1!$A$1,""+hh:mm"")"
```

Comment: Nice! I like moving that "+" into the format, neat.

Comment: Thanks. I think that is it! I just realized I had problems referencing `Sheet1!$A$1`